# How to use angular's $resource with TypeScript and d.ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-resource

With this TypeScript (based on some online course):

```
interface IProduct {
    productName: string
}

interface IProductResource extends ng.resource.IResource<IProduct> {
}

interface IDataAccessService {
    getProductService(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource>
}

class DataAccessService implements IDataAccessService {
    static $inject = ['$resource'];

    constructor(private $resource:ng.resource.IResourceService) {
    }

    getProductService():ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource> {
        return this.$resource("sampleUrl");
    }

}

angular.module('app').service('dataAccessService', DataAccessService);
```

I have a code that uses `dataAccessService`:

```
var obj : IProductResource = dataAccessService.getProductService().get();
```

`obj` has all angular's REST helper methods like $save/$delete, but I don't have access to interface `obj.productName`. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: how to define API actions and their definition? surly i need to define it inside this.$resource("sampleUrl"); , but there should be ts definitions too, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. It should be:

```
interface IProductResource
    extends ng.resource.IResource<IProduct>, IProduct {
}
```

Any comments on that?

Thanks!

Comment: That is what I did